# How to get list of running applications on remote computer using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

like this :

```
get-process -computername cname | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} | select-object name, mainwindowtitle
```

it is not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of running applications on remote computer using PowerShell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881439/how-to-get-list-of-running-applications-on-remote-computer-using-powershell)

Answer (score 2):

If you get empty values for the `mainwindowtitle` is correct beacause this property isn't avalaible for remote process. see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx) for the `NotSupportedException`!

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell remoting if you can.  That is, you need PowerShell V2 and need to enable PowerShell remoting on the remote system using `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`.  Once you're done with that you should be able to run a command on the remote system like so:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Get-Process *mail* | Where {$_.MainWindowHandle} | Select Name,MainWindowTitle} -Cred $cred
```

If you're on a domain and your credentials are valid on the remote system, you don't need to specify them via the -Credentials parameter.

Comment: it is error to run :Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {Get-Process *mail* | Where {$_.MainWindowHandle} | Select Name,MainWindowTitle} ....you can try it

Comment: I did try it before I posted it.  What error are you getting?  PSRemoting can be a bit tricky to get setup correctly.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me, MainWindowTitle is still blank like OP's issue.