# How to get list of running applications on remote computer using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

```
get-process -computername cname | where-object {$_.mainwindowhandle -ne 0} `
    | select-object name, mainwindowtitle
```

This doesn't work.

It can only get the name list, but can't show the mainwindowtitle list ...

Comment: This seams to work fine on the local machine.  You may not have access to the process window remotly.  I would attempt to do it with power shell remoting

Comment: But this question it's a repetition of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880907/how-to-get-list-of-running-applications-on-remote-computer-using-powershell !!

Answer (score 3):

When invoking the get-process cmdlet objects of type `System.Diagnostics.Process` are returned. If you check the [msdn documentation for the MainWindowHandle property of System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you can read:

*"You can get the MainWindowHandle property only for processes that are running on the local computer."*